# Language content tree

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I'm planning to do a project using Umbraco CMS but i have some question i'd like to clear.

Just to put you into context, i'll use umbraco to handle part of website's content and other database to handle other part. It wil be a multi-lang website but i dont want to use one content tree for each language.

Do you have some suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions other than one content tree par language (which is the easiest the manage for most non technical users):

- Use the **dictionary** for static text
- Use **child nodes** for language specific content: For each content type, create a child content type with all language specific fields.
- Use **tabs**: repeat all language specific fields for each language and preferably organize them in tabs per language. Use an consistent naming scheme so you can use a macro to retrieve the appropriate version.
- Use **relations** to link nodes which are translations of each other

This of course covers only the content managed in Umbraco.